# I'm not able to update update due to concurrency issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

this is the first question I post here on this page. I'm going to try to be as clear as possible. I have a Service model like such

```
public class DowntimeService
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Work_Center { get; set; }
    public string Asset_ID { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public DateTime? Start_Time { get; set;  }    
    public DateTime? End_Time { get; set;  }
}
```

where the `Start_Time` uses the `Getdate()` function from the SQL db. My problem is that when I try to update the `End_Time` property I get a concurrency error.

Here is my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Edit(int id, DowntimeService downtimeService)
 {
     if (id != downtimeService.ID)
     {
         return NotFound();
     }

     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         _context.Entry(downtimeService).State = EntityState.Modified;
         _context.Entry(downtimeService).Property(t => t.Start_Time).IsModified = false;   
         _context.Update(downtimeService);
         _context.SaveChanges();       
         return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
     }
     return View(downtimeService);
}
```

Any thoughts on how I can update the `end_Time` property?

[Here is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT7AA.jpg)

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: I don't really know how EF will behave with your date field being annotated as `Timestamp` but what happens if you remove it? `Timestamp` is not a date type even though it sounds like it should be.

Comment: @Crowcoder if I remove the Timestamp it works fine but I don't get the Getdate() funtion that's model on the sql table. Due to the application scope I won't like the users to input the date manually.

Comment: I don't understand how you are using `Getdate()`. If that is a default on the column it should work.

Comment: he probably modified the original migration and placed `GetDate()` sql function as the "default value"

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution that worked for me. I used the ModelBuilder to map the default value from the SQL table.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<DowntimeService>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(t => t.Start_Time)
                .HasColumnName("Start_Time")
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate())");

            });
        }
```

I fairly new to EF there is always something new to learn. Thanks guys.